# HTML5 Canvas Screenshot saved onto page?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, screenshot

I've seen all of the posts explaining how to save an HTML5 canvas screenshot as an image and opening that image in a new tab. However, I was hoping to take that screenshot and have the image appear in an already-allocated div on the SAME WEBPAGE after the screenshot is taken. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: duplication to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf

Comment: @sking this is not a duplicate question. I looked at that post previously. I am looking for a way to take that newly generated url and append it to my HTML to appear under my canvas.

Answer (score 0):

```
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
<div id="under_canvas"></div>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
//dataURL can directly be inserted into src of image
document.getElementById('under_canvas').innerHTML = '<img src="'+img+'"/>';
</script>
```